# Delete button in a Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I added a button in each row of my Jtable, but without action. The button "delete" must delete the row from my Jtable and also my database. I thought of using map, the map contains the row number and id in my database, but i'm stack, i couldn't continue with that logic.

**here is my code :**

```
public class Fenetre extends JFrame {

    Statement stmt;
    Map<Integer,Integer> row_table  = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
public Fenetre(){     
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("JTable");
    this.setSize(600, 140);

    String requeteListeUser=" SELECT * FROM COMPTE_UTILISATEUR";
    try{
    stmt= (Statement) new Connexion().getConnection().createStatement();
    ResultSet resultat= stmt.executeQuery(requeteListeUser);
     resultat.last(); 
     String  title[] = {"Nom","Prenom","Matricule","Action"};
     int rowCount = resultat.getRow();

     Object[][] data  = new Object[rowCount][4];

     JTable tableau = new JTable(data,title);

    // this.tableau = new JTable(model);
    tableau.getColumn("Action").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());

     this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(tableau), BorderLayout.CENTER); 

     int i=0;
        resultat.beforeFirst(); // on repositionne le curseur avant la première ligne 
        while(resultat.next()) //tant qu'on a quelque chose à lire
        {   
            //Remplire le tableau à deux dimensions Data[][] 
            for(int j=1;j<=4;j++)
            {
                 if(j != 4)data[i][j-1]=resultat.getObject(j)+"";
                 else data[i][j-1] = new JButton("Supprimer");

            }

            i++; 
            row_table.put(i, resultat.getInt("id_utilisateur"));

        }    
    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
    System.out.println(ex);
    }   
  }

  //Classe model customized
  class ZModel extends AbstractTableModel{
    private Object[][] data;
    private String[] title;

    //Constructor
    public ZModel(Object[][] data, String[] title){
      this.data = data;
      this.title = title;
    }

    //Number of columns
    public int getColumnCount() {
      return this.title.length;
    }

    //Number of rows
    public int getRowCount() {
      return this.data.length;
    }

    //The value at the specified  à l'emplacement spécifié
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
      return this.data[row][col];
    }   
  }

 public class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer{

 public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,Objectvalue,booleanisSelected, boolean isFocus, int row, int col) {
      //On écrit dans le bouton ce que contient la cellule
      setText("Suuprimer");
      //On retourne notre bouton
      return this;
     } }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Fenetre fen = new Fenetre();
    fen.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: explain a bit more where you stuck?

Comment: Where should I put the action of the button in my code ? and how this action would be ? 
my button  "delete" in each row must be delete the row from my Jtable and my database.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/). It shows how to use a JButton as a renderer and editor for a column. All you need to do is write the custom `Action` for the editor.

The link gives a simple example of a *Delete Action* that deletes a row from the `TableModel`. You would need to modify the `Action` to remove the row from the Database.

Comment: But i'm not using DefalutTableModel

Comment: I am using AbstractTableModel

Comment: No you are not using AbstractTableModel. You are extending AbstractTableModel and implementing your own functionality. So, if you want the ability to remove data from the TableModel, then you also need to implement a `removeRow(...)` method to do this. So you have a choice, either implement the functionality in your custom TableModel or use the DefaultTableModel because it has this functionality built in. Based on the code you posted there is no reason to create a custom TableModel, you can use the DefaultTableModel.

Comment: Action delete = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
        int modelRow = Integer.valueOf( e.getActionCommand() );
        ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).removeRow(modelRow);
    }
};
 
**ButtonColumn buttonColumn = new ButtonColumn(table, delete, 2);
buttonColumn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);**

Comment: Should I add these lines to my code ?? what does this line do **buttonColumn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D)** ??

Comment: Where should I put the actionPerformed please

Comment: Yes you need to add the code (how would it work otherwise?). You add the code AFTER you create the table and load it with data. The Action is required for the ButtonColumn class, so you need to create the Action before you create the ButtonColumn class.

Comment: It is not working :/ can u please tell me which part should I to my code to delete rows from my jtable and database

Comment: The link I gave you contains the code. If you can't copy the code then I can't help. The code you posted doesn't use the DefaultTableModel or the code I suggested and I am not a mind reader so I can't guess how you have modified your code to use my suggestion.

Comment: can u please help me, i'm still stack. I added an action to my button but it doesn't work and i don't know why. When I click the button nothing happens. Till now, I added the button to each row, but with no action. 

This is my code :

Comment: @user3862042, You haven't posted your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem, so no I can't help.